# How to remove 0 after country code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, input

I am using a jQuery plugin (http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes.html) on my form to submit date.
But sometimes by mistake peoples are adding 0 after country code.

For example instead of +97150975xxxx they submitting +971050975xxxx.
Is there any way to delete the zero after the country code? On blur

Comment: Can't you get country code and do substring from string then get 1st digit from remaining one to check whether it is 0 or not?

Comment: It looks like country codes can be between 2 and 4 integers long (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes). How would you know if it was a country code that was 3-4 characters long vs a 2 character long with the accidental 0?

Comment: Debin yes I can extract the country code var extension = $("#demo").intlTelInput("getExtension"); and the number var intlNumber = $("#demo").intlTelInput("getNumber");  and http://jsfiddle.net/kCpNQ/304/ will do the rest... correct?

Comment: Yeah then extract it and get first digit of remaining string..

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I stand corrected in regards to the codes. This might do the trick (haven't tested it myself):

```
var code = $("#demo").intlTelInput("getExtension");
var number = $("#demo").intlTelInput("getNumber");
var clean_number = code + number;
```

EARLIER: I'd rather extract the country code from the source string (first 4 characters), then extract the number (last 9 characters) and make the clean number out of them:

```
var source = '+971050975xxxx';
var code = source.substring(0, 4);
var number = source.substring(source.length - 9);
var clean_number = code + number;
```

Comment: Yes some country codes are longer than other. Cayman island is +1345 http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, updating with the altered generic function

```
<input id="demo" placeholder="e.g. +1 702 123 4567" type="tel" onblur="SetValue(this.value)">
```

and the javascript function for onblur i,

```
function SetValue(e)
{

    var selectedCountry = $("div[class='selected-flag']")[1].children[0].getAttribute("class").split(' ')[1];
    var countryCode = $("li[data-country-code='" + selectedCountry + "']").attr("data-dial-code");

    var prefixData = "+"+countryCode;
    var inputData = document.getElementById("demo").value;

    var tempData = inputData.replace(prefixData, '');

    if (tempData.indexOf(' ') == 0) {
        tempData = tempData.substring(1, tempData.length);
    }
    if (tempData.indexOf('0') == 0) {
        tempData = tempData.substring(1, tempData.length);
        document.getElementById("demo").value = prefixData +" "+ tempData;
    }           

}
```